# The LINQ expression could not be translated Rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have C# application and I have written the following LINQ expression.

```cs
var invoices = await this.Context
    .Set<InvoiceItem>().Where(x => x.Status == "Created")
    .Where(query.Filter)
    .OrderBy(query.Sort)
    .Paginate(pageInfo)
    .ToListAsync();

foreach (var item in invoices)
{
    item.ServiceEndDate = this.Context.InvoiceLineItems
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.InvoiceId == item.Id) != null 
            ? this.Context.InvoiceLineItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.InvoiceId == item.Id).ServiceEndDate 
            : null;
}
return invoices;
```

whenever this expression is executed i get the following error

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()\r\n    .Where(i => i.BusinessId == __ef_filter__BusinessId_0 || __ef_filter__IsMedCompliUser_1)\r\n    .Where(i => i.Status == "Created")\r\n    .Where(i => i.IsActive == __Value_0)\r\n    .OrderBy(i => (object)i.ServiceEndDate.Value)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of member 'ServiceEndDate' on entity type 'InvoiceItem' failed. This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped.\r\nTranslation of member 'ServiceEndDate' on entity type 'InvoiceItem' failed. This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable',

Part of model:

```cs
public class InvoiceItem : IHasTenant
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long BusinessId { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public DateTime? InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfService { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime? ServiceEndDate { get; set; }
```

PageInfo:

```cs
public class PageInfo : MedCompli.Common.Contracts.PageInfo
{
}

public static class PageInfoExtensions
{
    public static bool IsPageNumberValid(this PageInfo pageInfo)
    {
        return MedCompli.Common.Extensions.PageInfoExtensions.IsPageNumberValid(pageInfo);
    }

    public static bool IsPageSizeValid(this PageInfo pageInfo)
    {
        return MedCompli.Common.Extensions.PageInfoExtensions.IsPageSizeValid(pageInfo);
    }
}
```

Query:

```cs
namespace MedCompli.Core.Contracts
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Object that contains sorting and filtering parameters for an Entity Framework
    //     query.
    public class Query
    {
        public Query();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Filtering parameters.
        [FromQuery(Name = "q")]
        [JsonProperty("q")]
        public QueryFilter Filter { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Sorting parameters.
        [FromQuery(Name = "s")]
        [JsonProperty("s")]
        public IDictionary<string, SortOperator> Sort { get; set; }

        public virtual QueryFilter ConvertFilterProperties(IMapper mapper);
        public virtual IDictionary<string, SortOperator> ConvertSortProperties(IMapper mapper);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably `ServiceEndDate` is not mapped. Here you need DTO class for return. This query can be omptimized but I need model classes.

Comment: From EF Core 3, the implicit client evaluation has been disabled. That is why you get such error. Pls share what is your `query.Filter`, `query.Sort`,`pageInfo` detailed code and how is your model `InvoiceItem` like. Then we can reproduce your issue and give the solution to you.

Comment: I added the desired parts.

Comment: Why always part of model... Do you have navigation property `InvoiceItem.LineItems`?

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

> Translation of member 'ServiceEndDate' on entity type 'InvoiceItem' failed.

And the expression contains `OrderBy(i => (object)i.ServiceEndDate.Value)`
So the provider doesn't know how to map this condition, since the property is not mapped.

You need to either map this property or not use in query (conditions, sorting, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make not mapped property to be translatable, EF Core should know how this property is mapped to the database. In your case you have to project ALL properties manually with additional property `ServiceEndDate`

```cs
var invoices = await this.Context
    .Set<InvoiceItem>().Where(x => x.Status == "Created")
    .Selec(x => new InvoiceItem
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        BusinessId = x.BusinessId,
        IsActive = x.IsActive,
        InvoiceDate = x.InvoiceDate,
        DateOfService = x.DateOfService,
        ServiceEndDate = x.ServiceEndDate,

        // other propeties

        ServiceEndDate = (DateTime?)this.Context.InvoiceLineItems
            .Where(li => li.InvoiceId == item.Id)
            .Select(li => li.ServiceEndDate)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .Where(query.Filter)
    .OrderBy(query.Sort)
    .Paginate(pageInfo)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Note that `FirstOrDefault` has no sense without `OrderBy`.